# jQuery - Are visually stunning introductions possible?

Tags: jquery

I'm just about to take on a new client and one of their requirements is for a nice website introduction.  Normally I would do this in flash however I am just wondering if something along these lines would be possible with jQuery in this day and age - here is the description:

> For the intro I was thinking the loading bar can be a small blank map of California on a white screen, shading in gradually as the status reaches 100%.. when complete the map enlarges and the southern california area highlights.. the screen then zooms in on that area completely until we arrive at a white homepage with our content.

I know how to do the loading with jQuery, and I've done interactive zooming before with jQuery too, but this would need to be a pre-scripted chain of events.

Is it possible with jQuery?  If so, I might be interested in hiring someone to put it together for me as I have a fairly high workload right now, so if you think its possible and have a good idea how to do it, please answer here :-)

Zach

Comment: Sounds doable, at least if you don't need to support IE6

Comment: I'm not sure that website intros are good practice any longer. Is it a real loading bar, or is it there only to allow time for the intro?

Comment: Standard practice is to get the page loaded before the JavaScript (i.e. put the `<script>` tags at the end of the `<body>` section), so you don't have to worry about whether the element you're trying to manipulate even exists yet.  Ask your client if they want to intentionally delay the user's experience, or if they'd rather have it skip the "loading" stuff and start with the zooming map, or skip it altogether. Were there widespread support for SVG, you could do the whole thing with SVG + JavaScript.

Comment: The website is for a private membership benefits club and they want the introduction to showcase what they offer, almost like a promotional but only 10 or 15 seconds long.   It will be a real loading bar as some of the websites content will be sizable and require loading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.  The only issue is that JavaScript has no way of 'polling' the page to see how complete it is (which is, I believe, what you're trying to do -- have a 'loading' bar be a map?)

You could always poll for specific resources on the page and estimate the % complete, and of course 100% is easy to detect.